# Data frame data type conflict...conver

Tags: python-3.x

I am receiving the error below upon running a python file.

'invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'data missing'

It looks as though some of the data in my dataframe is not of a type compatable with an arithmetic operation I would like to perform.

Can someone advise on how I might be able to locate the position of data that is giving the error?  And or bypass the entire error with a preprocessing step that allows for the normalization step?

I am confused because missing data should be dropped with the df1.dropna and if not there

The original line throwing the error was the line used to normalize the data. (last line below)

i've tried to convert the dataframe with

```
 df1 = df1.astype(int)



df1 = pd.concat([df2,df3], axis = 1, join_axes = [df2.index])
df1 = df1.fillna(method = 'bfill')
df1 = df1.dropna(axis =0)
df1 = df1.astype(int)
df1 = (df1 - df1.min())/(df1.max() - df1.min())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u should try df1.dtypes to check the data type of each column first

here is the documentation of that:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Comment: print(df1.dtypes) yields error: valueerror: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'data missing'